# Difference between Discrete and Continuous Solver in MATLAB Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I want to understand the difference between Discrete and Continuous Solver in MATLAB Simulink.

Could anyone explain me this difference in a simple language with examples.

Answer (score 2):

A state for the discrete solver consists only of values. A state for the continuous solver has values AND state derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

In very plain terms, the continuous solvers are used (required) when you have continuous states, for example when using a continuous integrator or derivative block. Conversely, the discrete solvers are used/recommended when you have only discrete states, e.g. a discrete integrator or derivative block. The Simulink diagnostics will flag any solver compatibility issues.

For more details, have a look at the documentation, in particular this page on [choosing a solver](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/choosing-a-solver.html).